# Maven artifact not uploaded with pom file

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, nexus

I have a backend multimodule maven project, that is build on jenkins with `mvn clean package` command (maven version 3.3). After a sucessfull build I upload two of the maven subprojects `target/*.jar` to private nexus (using `Nexus artifact uploader` plugin). The jars from target folders are uploaded correctly, but the pom is not (there is no option in the plugin to upload the pom).

Then I have my webapp project, where I have dependency to the two artifacts on my private nexus. They are found and downloaded, but not the pom. Building the webapp project fails, because the dependencies are not resolved for the two jars. A warning is printed out during build:

```
[WARNING] The POM for <groupId>:<submodule-artifactId>:jar:1.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
```

That is reasonable - I can clearly see in nexus repository that it has only jar, md5 and sha files. How should I build my multimodule maven project in a way I would be able to reference only submodules in my webapp project? Or should I upload the submodule projects poms manualy?

I am open to upload the whole backend project to nexus, but I would like to be able to add only subprojects as dependencies to my webapp.

Comment: Did you specify the distributionManagement in your POM.xml (https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management)?

Comment: @D.Lawrence no, I assumed I dont need that when I am not using `mvn deploy` command

Comment: You still need to tell maven where to look for your artifacts in your private nexus

Comment: @D.Lawrence uhm I dont understand, in my webapp (which has dependency to the jars) I have repository specified - the jars are downloaded correctly. The distributionManagement should be used to deploy artifacts using `maven deploy` command, or not?

Comment: You are correct, my bad. I was mistaken by the repository definition in the distributionManagement and the general concept of repositories as explained here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html

Comment: I think you have to treat the pom as seperate artifact if you want to use the artifactUploaderJob. Alternatively you could use the maven deploy plugin which would automatically deploy the jar and the pom.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a private nexus, you need to specify in your maven where to look for your artifact. Usually the way to do it is to specify a `repository` configuration in your pom.xml as specified in [this link](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html). This will tell maven to contact your private nexus for your artifacts.